# Checking access modifiers of methods

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, scope, namespaces

I wonder if there is a way to check the access modifier of a method within it's class. For instance I would like to use the remap-method of Codeigniter for an account-system:

```
public function _remap($method, $params = array()){

    if($this->validation->isValidActiveSession()){

        if(method_exists($this, $method))
            call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
        else
            show_404();

    }else{

        redirect('login');

    }

}
```

If I cant find a valid session for a user, he gets denied. I also want to make sure, that a user who has a proper session, can only call public methods. Unfortunately *method_exists()* returns true regardless whether the method is public or private.

I already have solutions for this specific problem:

- Not using remap and validate the session in every public method
- using an array that stores available methods for valid users

but it feels inconvenient, so I'm just looking for a 'fancier' solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Reflectionmethod](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php)

```
$reflection = new ReflectionMethod($this, $method);
    if ($reflection->isPublic()) {
        echo "Public method";
    }
   if ($reflection->isPrivate()) {
        echo "Private method";
    }
   if ($reflection->isProtected()) {
        echo "Protected method";
    }
```